# Unknown file system error ubuntu

Tags: grub2, partitioning, encryption, data-recovery

Trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Kali. While trying to encrypt the Kali partition I mistakenly encrypted both Ubuntu and Kali partitions and also the Ubuntu swap space. When I realized this I tried to undo the changes and deleted the Kali partition.

Then I restarted my PC and I get a filesystem error and grub rescue.  In grub rescue I can't seem seem to find my root partition. I keep getting unknown filesystem on each partition. I have a live gparted disk that shows that the Ubuntu partition is encrypted.

How can I recover my data?

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? The output of `sudo lsblk -f` would probably enough to for a start if that's more convenient for you. Thanks.

Comment: **To close/reopen voters:** The linked question doesn't deal with encrypted file systems and none of the tools suggested in its answer support the recovery of the content of encrypted file systems (without previous decryption through other means).

Answer (score 0):

With many types of encryption there is always a key, sometimes two keys. Those keys are usually stored in the partitions sector, or some support sector that the partition sector knows about. When you deleted the partition you may have deleted any keying and password data that is used to decrypt the data. If that has happened then your data is gone.

Now, did you encrypt your entire root partition? If you did how long did it take? When you deleted the partition how long did that take?

Unless there is some kind of master key that will decrypt the data no matter what then the encrypted data is probably gone.